# WooCommerce - How can we change Shipping Address to N/A in order emails?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce provides various hooks and action to change the predefined templates. But i need to hide the shipping address from order emails and display N/A. I have created a custom shipping method using plugin. Using that plugin i have to changed the address.
Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, i found a solution :

```
function myplugin_plugin_path() {
        return untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_locate_template', 'myplugin_woocommerce_locate_template', 10, 3 );


    function myplugin_woocommerce_locate_template( $template, $template_name, $template_path ) {

      global $woocommerce;
      $_template = $template;

      if ( ! $template_path ) $template_path = $woocommerce->template_url;
            $plugin_path  = myplugin_plugin_path() . '/woocommerce/';

      $template = locate_template(  array(
                                    $template_path . $template_name,
                                    $template_name));

      // Modification: Get the template from this plugin, if it exists
      if ( ! $template && file_exists( $plugin_path . $template_name ) )
        $template = $plugin_path . $template_name;

      // Use default template

      if ( ! $template )
        $template = $_template;
      return $template;

    }
```

The normal WooCommerce template loader searches the following locations in order:

1. your theme / template path / template name
2. your theme / template name
3. your plugin / woo-commerce / template name
4. default path / template name

Reference Link : https://www.skyverge.com/blog/override-woocommerce-template-file-within-a-plugin/